# Is it possible in Spring Batch to merge read lines that aren't next to each other before a write

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

There is a file that needs to be processed and altered to create a new file that is a "transpose" of the existing file.

There are pairs within the file with a common identifier 'id' however the file does not have these lines next to each other. The file structure looks as follows

```
D|ABC|12345|example1|example2
D|ABC|67890|example1|example2
D|ABC|121212|example1|example2
D|DEF|example3|12345|example4|
D|DEF|example3|67890|example4|
D|DEF|example3|121212|example4|
```

The intended output would be

```
D|ABC|12345|example1|example2|D|DEF|example3|12345|example4|
D|ABC|67890|example1|example2|D|DEF|example3|67890|example4|
D|ABC|121212|example1|example2|D|DEF|example3|121212|example4|
```

I have a PatternMatchingCompositeLineMapper that can determine which object to map a line to but i am unsure on how to manage this to allow the processor to merge the lines as a peekableItemReader is only for the following line.

Or is it simpler to write each type to a new file, then have a second step that would then read the two files and merge there?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://github.com/fmbenhassine/spring-batch-lab/tree/main/issues/so53366710) can help. He is merging more than one file, but maybe you can reuse something.

Comment: How would you do that *without* Spring Batch? Do you have an algorithm to solve this requirement? If you share your solution, I will try to help you implement it with Spring Batch.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine are you asking me how I would do this without batch? My plan is to use spring batch. The input file has 1-1 pairs they just aren't aligned next to each other in the input file

Comment: @Pp88 this looks like it is close to what I need. I think splitting the initial input file into two new files and then ingesting them is the correct solution

Comment: The project is of @MahmoudBenHassine so… :) better to explain him your needs

Comment: Yh I did see that!

Answer (score 0):

I see no need to use the fork/join model linked in the comment. The way I would approach this is by using a staging table (in a SQLite DB for instance), and use a SQL query to group items by the required field.

This way, you would have a regular chunk-oriented step that reads data from a table and writes records to a file.

Comment: There would still be a first job then to insert the original file into the table?

Comment: A first step, not a first job. You would need a single job with 3 steps: staging step, processing step, and cleanup step.

Comment: So create an empty 'parent' class. 2 classes extend off that than are a part of the composite line mapper. These are inserted into 2 tables.

Next step use a join to read these as objects are a part of a new class that contains both of the above children within?